# Using the pandas module can I take part of a column instead of all of it?

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 0        1        2        3        4     5  6
0  2018.12.0400:00  0.73572  0.73614  0.73544  0.73550   520  0
1  2018.12.0401:00  0.73550  0.73594  0.73545  0.73553  1181  0
2  2018.12.0402:00  0.73553  0.73606  0.73510  0.73539  1960  0
3  2018.12.0403:00  0.73539  0.73621  0.73481  0.73608  2898  0
```

If I want to find the average of column 2 row 0-1 and column 2 row 2-3, how would I do that using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df.loc[0:1, '2'].mean()
```

and

```
df.loc[2:3, '2'].mean()
```

Comment: ahh i keep putting a : in front of the 2 haha thank you so much!